Android端末でUnityのTouchScreenKeyboardTypeが動作しない
Unityで英数字のみ使用できるテキスト入力機能を作りたいです。
しかし、Android端末でTouchScreenKeyboard.OpenにTouchScreenKeyboardType.ASCIICapableを指定しても日本語キーボードが開いてしまいます。
TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.ASCIICapable);

TMPro_InputFieldを使用しても同様の現象が発生します。
他のキーボードの例では、TouchScreenKeyboardType.NumberPadのような数字キーボード指定は正しく開きますが、TouchScreenKeyboardType.URLのような英字キーボード指定は日本語キーボードが開いてしまいます。
端末のキーボード設定に影響されずに英字キーボードを開く方法はありますか？
